# get and rotate all next similar components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assume I have a component named *Square* and put some of them inside the app. I want to have one of them be *active* and all next *Square* components rotated based on index of that one. something like this:

```
<div className="app">
  <Square className={""}/>
  <Square className={"square--active"}/>
  <Square className={""}/>
  <Square className={""}/>
</div>
```

I pass active className as a prop. so here because the second one is active, second *Square* and third and forth should be rotated 90 degrees. I know how to do it in vanilla JS **But** how can I do this properly in reactish way?

EDIT: I try to show it by a visual example:
[image]

here you see after clicking on the second square the second one and all sqaures after it rotated 90 degress. but if I click on the third one, third and forth one should rotate 180 degrees.

I hope it is clear now.
thanks.

Comment: your question is not clear, your logic is not clear, and you provide insufficient codes for us to understand your intention. Provide more codes else we will be wasting time answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If index of `Square` to be active is fixed, you can simply add a custom classNames to the following `Square`s (and add styles for it inside the component) like this:

```
<div className="app">
  <Square className=""/>
  <Square className="square--active square--rotated"/>
  <Square className="square--rotated"/>
  <Square className="square--rotated"/>
  <Square className="square--rotated"/>
</div>
```

If the active index is a variable and sent to you as a prop, it's more complex but you can do it too. Here's a rough solution:

```
<div className="app">
  <Square className={getSquareClassName(0)}/>
  <Square className={getSquareClassName(1)}/>
  <Square className={getSquareClassName(2)}/>
  <Square className={getSquareClassName(3)}/>
</div>
```

And in your component:

```
const getSquareClassName = idx => {
  if (idx === index) { // index is the prop/state of the active square
    return 'square--active square--rotated';
  } else if (idx > index) {
    return 'square--rotated';
  }

  return '';
};
```

Comment: no, it's not fixed, it changes when some one click on one of them, if you click on the second one, it should be set to active

Comment: ok, updated. hopefully it gives you an idea.

Comment: I like your answer, but waiting maybe there is a better one. if there is nothing, so this is the answer. thanks.